# how to create a maze in 2-D array

Tags: python

I'm Solving a question on solving a maze and printing the path that pops the question into my mind.. is there any algorithm to create a maze.

Say we have a 2-D array of any size

```
for ex:array = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]   

1 -> no wall  0 -> wall
```

I just want to create the maze... not solving

although I did find some algorithm on Wikipedia like recursive backtracking and I don't understand how to apply those algorithms in nodes.

So anyone can help me with that..?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

1. Set the whole map to all walls. Select an entrance and an exit, setting these two locations to no walls;
2. Randomly choose a wall and flip it to no wall;
3. Test whether the exit is accessible from the entrance with BFS/DFS;
4. If not accessible then goto 2 else goto 5;
5. Maze is successfully created.

Comment: i tried..let's just say I have matrix of (20x50) this make my algorithm quite slow

Comment: Don't write computation-intensive code in Python. With native language (C++/Rust/etc) you may easily get an impressive <100ms speed in such a small map size.

Comment: Also, you should post your python code so people can give you suggestions to improve.

Comment: You may also iterate through wiki and try with a fastest algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: this is the page I was referred to in my post .. they are using simple lines as walls but I want to use the cell(in 2d array) as a wall.. problem is I don't know how to use these concepts in cell